# svn on commit adds additional files

Tags: svn, version-control, command-line

The problem is svn on commit adds additional files which have not been updated.

Example:

```
svn st
```

This shows `file1` as being changed

```
svn commit
```

This uploads the changes in `file1` and well as `file2, file3, file4`

This always happens to the same files

```
file2, file3, file4
```

How can I stop this?

SVN Version:

> Subversion command-line client, version 1.6.6

Comment: Are `file2, file3, file4` changed in anyway?  Or are they always the same and it commits them anyway?

Comment: Can you try svn commit .

Comment: Can you try `svn commit file1`?

Comment: @AndrewCox file2, file3, file4 never change

Comment: @Neil I could but this could get cumbersome with merge and commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of the Subversion client are you using?

In pre-subversion 1.7 clients, Subversion determines file changes by looking at the content of the file and the stored base in the `.svn` directory. Subversion compares both the properties and the content of the file itself to determine any changes. For example:

```
$ svn up
U file1
U file2
U file3
```

In this example, you'll see at least these six files:

```
.svn/text-base/file1.svn-base
.svn/text-base/file2.svn-base
.svn/text-base/file3.svn-base
.svn/prop-base/file1
.svn/prop-base/file2
.svn/prop-base/file3
```

It does not look at the timestamp to determine whether or not a file has changed (like Makefile would have).

Both `svn up` and `svn commit` use the same algorithm to determine whether or not a file should be recorded as being modified.

There's also a file called `.svn/entries` that contains a list of entries that the directory has. This allows Subversion to track additions and deletions, but it is not used for detecting changes.

I've see issues during a merge where an *unchanged file* is being committed. However, this always shows up when doing a `svn status`, and the file contents weren't changed but the property `svn:merge info` was.

Your issue seem very different. First of all, you don't see the changes when doing a `svn status`, but they do get committed. What if you do a `svn -v log` on the directory? Do the files show up as being changed? What if you do a `svn status -v`? This will show all files including ones that are ignored and ones that have not been changed.

It's the client that tells the server what files have been changed, and not the server determining which files to commit. Therefore, the issue is with your Subversion client:

What is your Subversion client and what OS do you have? I know the Cgywin can be problematic -- especially if you *share* your working directory with the Windows Subversion client. There can be some issues with sharing a working directory between two different types of clients (like a GUI client and a command line client). For example, VisualStudio's AnkhSvn client creates `_svn` directories. TortoiseSVN can use them (if you configure it correctly), but not the standard Subversion command line.

And, of course, the 1.7 command line client is way different from the earlier command line clients. In the standard 1.7 command line client, the `.svn` directory is only in the root, and I believe it uses checksums to determine whether or not a file's content has been changed.

Sorry I couldn't provide any further assistance. Maybe I gave you something to go on? Let me know your Subversion client and OS, and that might help. Also let me know if you use multiple Subversion clients in the same directory. That might be a clue too.

I've tried going into `$HOME/.subversion/conf` to see if there's any setting there that might make a difference, but I found nothing that would cause this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to always ignore the files you can use [svn:ignore](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/662.cfm) but if they are files that you do sometimes change and you need to have them under source control I would do an `svn diff file1` and go from there.  What type of files are they and what is the result of the diff?

Comment: but nothing has changed with the files

Comment: they are .pdf files that might change twice a year

Comment: @PhillPafford if svn stat says they've changed then there must be some svn diff output?

Comment: That's the problem, executing svn st I only get the changed files which is what I expect but doing a merge/commit I get extra files added and I don't know why

Comment: `svn:ignore` is only for files that have not yet been added into the repository. `svn:ignore` only affects the way `svn status` works (which won't report files with `?`) and how `svn add *` works (won't add files). In this case, the files have already been added (thus they get committed) and they haven't changed (thus don't show up in `svn status`).